Grouping jobs locally with Snakemake
Is there a way to group jobs locally on Snakemake?
I am trying to create a Snakemake pipeline using prefetch to download a large set of fastq files from SRA and generate bam files. Despite being a straightforward problem that I can execute for a few samples, when I try to scale up locally I run into a storage problem. When I try to run the pipeline for 100 samples, it tries to download all the fastq files from rule 1 before processing them with the following rules.
My pipeline has all the steps before the final bam file marked as temporary, so storage won't be a problem after everything is analyzed and fastq files are deleted.
It wouldn't be a problem if I could run 10 samples at a time, deleting the temporary outputs before downloading new fastq files.
I tried to group the jobs and give snakemake 10 cores, thinking that it would download 10 samples and run them through the entire pipeline before getting to the 11th. But I realize that groups don't work locally and it didn't work.
I also tried pipe to test. I changed the output from the prefetch rule from "temporary()" to "pipe()". Piping prefetch into fasterq-dump works outside of snakemake but outputs an "error in group..." when I try it on snakemake because it seems like fasterq-dump is trying to read the file before it is downloaded.
This is the start of the snakemake code that I am using to test this pipe approach:
rule prefetch:
    input: 
    output:
        pipe(os.path.join(config['all_path']['sra_down'], "{srasample}/{srasample}.sra"))
    wildcard_constraints: srasample="|".join(list(config['fastq_sra_HE'].values()))
    params: 
        sraID="{srasample}",
        srapath=expand(config["all_path"]["sra_down"])
    shell: "prefetch {params.sraID} -O {params.srapath}"

rule fasterqdump:
    input: os.path.join(config['all_path']['sra_down'], "{srasample}/{srasample}.sra")
    output: r1=temporary(os.path.join(config['all_path']['sra_down'], "{srasample}_1.fastq")),
        r2=temporary(os.path.join(config['all_path']['sra_down'], "{srasample}_2.fastq"))
    wildcard_constraints: srasample="|".join(list(config['fastq_sra_HE'].values())), r=["1","2"]
    params: 
        sraID=os.path.join(config['all_path']['sra_down'], "{srasample}"),
        srapath=expand(config["all_path"]["sra_down"])
    shell:
        "fasterq-dump {params.sraID} -O {params.srapath}"

This is the error:
2024-11-21T16:14:51 fasterq-dump.2.11.3 err: invalid accession '/disco2/tiago/worldpops/SRR204016'
fasterq-dump quit with error code 3
[Thu Nov 21 13:14:52 2024]
Error in group ffb6a5f4-6dee-447e-9a2e-2dea42295399:
    jobs:
        rule fasterqdump:
            jobid: 3
            output: /disco2/tiago/worldpops/SRR204016_1.fastq, /disco2/tiago/worldpops/SRR204016_2.fastq
        rule prefetch:
            jobid: 4
            output: /disco2/tiago/worldpops/SRR204016/SRR204016.sra (pipe)

Shutting down, this might take some time.


Any help on how to tackle this would be appreciated.
Best,
Tiago

If your final rule has a higher priority, snakemake would try to execute it as fast as possible. So if you have 10 cores, and each rule only requires one core, it should be what you are looking for.
Disclaimer: I have not tested it, but from my understanding, this should do the trick.

I just tried giving priority 2 to "prefetch" rule and priority 1 to "fasterq-dump" rule, as well as enforcing 1 core for each, but I still get the same error. Could it be an issue with trying to pipe these two rules?

I never used pipe(), but judging from the documentation, I don't think that this would cause a problem. But giving prefetch a higher priority would not work. From your explanation I assumed you have an additional rule which processes the fastqFiles from your dump rule, this rule is the one which should get the highest priority. So it gets executed as fast as possible and all related fastq-Files can be deleted.

Thanks @kEks, I changed the priority from all the rules increasingly (prefetch with 0 and the last one with the highest number). I also stepped away from pipe() and used temporary() for prefetch, since the data has to be downloaded anyway. It's been working so far, but sometimes prefetch (priority 0) still gets called before higher priority rules. It seems like the priority is increasing the chance of other rules starting before prefetch, but does not guarantee that they will. But it is working so far, if I run it with few threads.

In addition to priority, you can set a resource to limit the number of prefetch jobs to run at once.  It's not ideal; if fasterqdump is significantly slower you can still run out of space depending on the scheduler.  The idea is:
rule prefetch:
    input: 
    output: ...
    resources:
        prefetch_jobs=1

Then you execute snakemake with --resources prefetch_jobs=5, which will limit prefetch to only 5 jobs simultaneously.  Combined with 10 cores and your priorities, as a prefetch finishes the fasterqdump will start.  You can tune the resource if you feel like it's too much of a bottleneck or still too much downloads.  I frequently use something like that to limit downloads or jobs that generate giant files.

That might just do the job for me! Thank you, I added this line and am running the code again to test.
